# QByteArray conversion to char (not char* or constChar*)

Tags: c++, qt, char, serial-port, qbytearray

I have an issue which has been bugging for over an hour and decided just to ask here. Is there a proper way of converting a QByteArray to a char? I managed to get it working as char* but I need to pass it as a char.

Here is a code bit where I take the qbytearray and convert it to char*:

```
    QByteArray MainWindow::checkSum(QByteArray &b)
    {
        qint16 b_len = b.length();

        char xor = 0;

        for ( int i = 0 ; i < b_len ; i ++ )
        {
           xor = xor ^ b[i];
        }

        return b;
    }

    void MainWindow::on_flipHorzButton_clicked()
    {
         // getFirmwareVersion = { 0xe6, 0x05, 0x12, 0x00}
         QByteArray str;

         char ch = checkSum(str).data();

         str[0] =0xaa;
         str[1] =0xbb;
         str[2] =0xcc;
         str[3] =0xdd;
         str[4] = ch;
         printf("%s", str[4]);
         serial.write(str, 5); 
}
```

Should I try to convert **ch** to char? If yes, how should I do it?

Comment: It's kinda unclear what you want. just char - is 1 character

Comment: I am in the process of adding additional code. Give me one second. :)

Comment: Why? What do you want a *single character* for? How could a whole string of characters ever fit in the single byte a `char` provides? What is the *actual* problem you want to solve ([related reading about the XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/))?

Comment: In case you need to pass a single char to some method/function make sure the `ch` points to the character of your interest and simply dereference it (`*ch`)

Comment: I just added the rest of the code I wanted to add. I hastily posted the question without adding the rest of the things I wanted for which I appologise!

Comment: @JoeCarr it's stll strange what you want. You are assigning char* to char, is this ever compiles?

Comment: @Starl1ght It does compile when I have ch as a char* but str[4] would give me a problem.

Comment: str[4] is 4th element of str, you probably want to print whole string? then put just str.data()

Comment: Because I want to use the checkSum value in str[4]?

Comment: why don't you change the return type of your `checkSum` function to `char`?

Comment: I tried doing that but almost everything in checkSum broke then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason I had to rename "xor" to something else.

For your specific problem, you have to change that line :

```
char ch = checkSum(str).data()[0];
```

So that it returns the first character of the char* from the QByteArray

Comment: As PsiX also noted, be careful with your "xor". It's a reserved word and might cause issues in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not work as **xor** is a reserved keyword: [xor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/xor)
Rename the variable to something else.